# Python Regex extractall for (YYYY) only but not MMM YYYY

Tags: python, regex

I have dataframe df with a column (textline) that consists of text

```
df['textline'].iloc[0] = 'This is a test with 2018\n'
df['textline'].iloc[1] = 'This is a test with Jan 2018\n'
df['textline'].iloc[2] = 'This is a test with Feb 2018\n'
```

I want to use Regex extractall to run through the entire df['textline'] but it will only extract the year when there is no preceeding Month names.  For example, in the above example, it will extract 2018 from the first line, but not the 2018 from the second or third line because it has the Jan or Feb (or other months).

```
df['textline'].str.extractall(r'<<Regex code>>')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: That is what I am looking for:  the regex pattern to do this.

Comment: In addition, please extend the regex code to not pick up lines with content such as January 2018, Jan 2018, etc.  I only want the lines with pure 2018 (no months)

Comment: E.g. here is the attempt:  
df['textline'].str.extractall(r' ^(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[a-z]* (\d{4})\D')

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the first part of the answer:

```
df['textline'].str.extractall(r'(?<!Jan|Feb) ([1-2][0-9]{3})')
```

The second part is how to use the same line for the entire word January , February so that it will work for both Feb 2018 and February 2018

Answer (score -1):

may you try this:

```
(?<=(\s))\d{4}(?=\D)
```

---

Matches:

This is a test with **2018**\n

This is a test with Jan **2018**\n

This is a test with Feb **2018**\n